# How to create triggers using Google API

Tags: google-apps-script

Do I have a possibility to add a trigger not only on spreadsheet?
I mean if I want some script be executed when I log in my mail box. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it for yourself to see if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a trigger from a spreadsheet event or time based, nothing else for now, this is clearly explained in the [online documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_triggerbuilder)...

I agree with the former comment, this is kind of an inappropriate question...